# Redirect all URLs to a file, except those pointing to a certain directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all URLs to index.php, so this URL:

> domain.com/home/stats

will point to:

> domain.com/index.php

instead.

However, I do not want URLs which point to the "public" directory, like:

> domain.com/public/images

to redirect to index.php.

I have tried many different rewrites which I found on this website, however none have work 100% so far. They all have just redirected every URL to index.php, even if you are trying to get to the public directory.

Here is what I have now:

```
RewriteRule !^/public/.*$ index.php
```

I know very little about RegEx, but it is my understanding that using the "!" character means "except for this". But apparently, in this case, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(public/.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

The second line is to let the URI as it is.  The third line is to avoid index.php be catch in an infinite loop.  The first and second `ReWriteRule` should stop (`[L]`) as soon as they processed.  The last one applies for everything else.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that didn't quite preform how I would like either, but after a little more searching yesterday I was able to find something else which did what I needed.

Comment: In such case, you should add an answer indicating how you solved it (and accept your own answer).  In that way, everybody learn.